# What is the best ERROR model for REST

Tags: spring, rest, architecture, restful-architecture

Is there a standard error message model for REST services?

I'm building a REST service, with Spring REST backend, and Backbone JS based frontend. On all projects, that I was there were some home made error messages mechanism, with home made client interpretation of those errors. This usually had a limited scope and use for this specific project.

Now in my current project I came to a point, where I want to introduce field errors for invalid JSON fields in POST requests. So I need to extend my model to support this.

From my point of view, it's yet another bicycle, since field validation is pretty standard requirement our days, so I wonder, if there is already an Error model, that I could reuse in my project.

I'm well familiar with HandlerExceptionResolver in Spring, and @Valid annotation in Java. In fact I'm using them allot. This is more of an architecture kind Question, what is the best model to communication this kind of errors to an independent JS client.

Comment: You have to use HTTP status codes and messages (aka self-descriptibe message constraint) and in the body you can describe the error in a more specific way, e.g. with multilanguage error messages and custom error codes. Be aware that the error message goes to the end user, who do not care about the exact Exception type, etc... You can send an extended error message to developers by debug mode.

Comment: I'm asking about the model for error body:) Now I see 2 classifications - errors in fields, logical errors, basically I'm asking what is a bigger picture, what is missing besides field errors & global errors.

Comment: I think a standard is missing to decouple the client from the implementation of the service. [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/spec/latest/core/) does have one. I don't know about other error types if you are asking that. By field errors you obviously have to use some CompositeException, by general errors you have to use a simple Exception. After that you have to convert that into json, xml, etc... and that's all. I don't think it is hard.

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is create a `ValidationError` model. The model is returned to the client as JSON in the case of a validation error, along with an HTTP status code, and it contains everything the client needs to know about the error.

The specifics of the model varies, but something like this would be a good start:

```
public class ValidationError {
    private int code;

    private String message;

    private Map<String, String> fields;

    /*...*/
}
```

Now when an invalid form is submitted, the JSON response will be something like:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "invalid form value(s)",
  "fields": {
    "username": "the username already exists",
    "password": "password must be more than 6 characters"
  }
}
```

This ties up nicely with Spring's `@ExceptionHandler`. When you get something like a `BindException`, all you have to do is:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
private ValidationError handleBindException(BindException ex) {
    ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError();
    /* set code and message */
    for (FieldError error : ex.getFieldErrors()) {
        /* set fields' errors */
    }
    return validationError;
}
```

`BindException` makes it easy to get the fields' errors. More work is needed to dig up the errors from exceptions like `JsonMappingException`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the best approach is validation both on the server and on the client. I'll limit my advice to the client, as I'm not familiar with Spring: Backbone does have a `validate` method for use with your  Backbone models. [The Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) encourage you to override this method with your own validation logic. `validate` gets called by default whenever you do a backbone model `save` (i.e. POST), and you can also trigger the `invalid` event whenever you want to run the validate code (for example,  after a key-up, before the user clicks the submit button).

If you're not keen on writing a lot of custom front-end validation, there are some plugins available, for example [backbone.validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation).

Comment: Thanks, already using backbone.validation, it's a great library. I want eventually to get transperency of error messages, whether it's client validation or server validation errors, this means I need to be able to translate server errors to backbone validation errors, but I would rather reuse existing model, than invent a wheel:)